# Uploading Image to Form Filled with Python Selenium Doesn't Work

Tags: python

I'm sure I'm requesting to the right place, the image is not uploading, the operation is waiting without error

macOSS
Chrome
Python 3.8
Selenium

```
browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//button[@jscontroller="soHxf"]')[1].send_keys("./img1.jpg")
            sleep(2)
```

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Comment: please provide url

Comment: So what's the exact request Python is sending versus a legitimate one from the browser? Including headers and all that? You should post the comparison here.

Comment: give atleast url and reproduce able code